# How to get `item_scraped_count` after Scrapy Spider is closed - Python27

Tags: python, scrapy

Whenever s Spider is finished, scrapy shows this in Terminal/CLI.

```
{'downloader/exception_count': 2,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.internet.error.TimeoutError': 2,
 'downloader/request_bytes': 58010,
 'downloader/request_count': 157,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 157,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 1151051,
 'downloader/response_count': 155,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 136,
 'downloader/response_status_count/403': 19,
 'file_count': 9,
 'file_status_count/downloaded': 1,
 'file_status_count/uptodate': 8,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 23, 15, 8, 36, 325285),
 'item_scraped_count': 10,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 203,
 'log_count/ERROR': 57,
 'log_count/INFO': 289,
 'log_count/WARNING': 1354,
 'request_depth_max': 3,
 'response_received_count': 135,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 156,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 156,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 156,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 156,
 'spider_exceptions/AttributeError': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 23, 15, 0, 9, 832308)}
```

But I want to access this whole Dictionary in code when spider is done running.  I have this method being executed whenever a spider is finished running.

```
def spider_closed(self, spider):
    stats = spider.crawler.stats.get_stats() 
    self.logger.info("Spider is being closed")
    self.logger.info(stats)
```

Its output does not include `item_scraped_count`, rather its output is very useless to me. Its output is

```
{'log_count/DEBUG': 40, 'scheduler/dequeued': 28, 'log_count/INFO': 74, 'downloader/response_count': 28, 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 24, 'response_received_count': 28, 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 425, 'downloader/response_bytes': 273395, 'finish_reason': 'shutdown', 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 23, 18, 20, 21, 580932), 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 28, 'scheduler/enqueued': 425, 'downloader/response_status_count/403': 4, 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 23, 18, 21, 20, 867566), 'downloader/request_bytes': 9566, 'request_depth_max': 2, 'log_count/WARNING': 1, 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 28, 'downloader/request_count': 28}
```

Comment: it should actually work, where are you defining this `spider_closed` method? did you link it to the `signals.spider_closed`.

Comment: @eLRuLL yes .... its `dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)` inside `__init` of Spider

Comment: looks like you've configured something incorrectly. I just checked and with the configuration you showed so far, the stats contain should contain the information. Also your printed `self.logger.info(stats)` is very different to the terminal stats you showed before. Try not assigning any signal and just using the `def close(self, reason)` method inside your spider (as it is the default closing method).

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be because the run was interrupted or terminated(?) since the `finish_reason` is `shutdown` and not `finished` in your last example . Maybe no items were scraped at all and that's why there is no `item_scraped_count` key?